# How to stop imageview any degree with rotateanimation on Android

Tags: android, rotateanimation

I have a problem with rotate animation. I want my image to stop where I want as degree.I can stop it where I wanted but It goes to starting degree again..

Such as, it starts 0 degree and I wanted to stop it in 270 degree. Its ok but after halfsecond it goes to 0 degree again. I want it to fixed

```
                RotateAnimation r = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 990.0f,0,bottle.getWidth()/2,0,bottle.getHeight()/2);
            r.setDuration((long) 2*500);
           r.setRepeatCount(0);

          bottle.startAnimation(r);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into adding:

```
r.setFillAfter(true);
```

or

```
r.setFillEnabled(true);
```

If these don't work you, may need to rotate the image manually in the onAnimationEnd(), which I've done successfully with translateAnimation, but I have not tried it for a rotateAnimation.

Comment: thank you, I have already solved my problem with        r.setFillAfter(true);